# how to convert the string to integer in java if the string is like String str=" 1234";?

Tags: java, string

how to convert the string to integer in java if the string is like this:

```
String str="  1234";
```

note  there is space in the beginning of the string. i tried `Integer.parseTnt(str)` method. But java shows `NumberFormatException`. Help me how to do?

Answer (score 4):

Try this one    `Integer.parseInt(str.trim());`

Answer (score 1):

Trim the string, it will remove space then parse it using `Integer#parseInt`.

```
String str =" 1234";
Integer i = Integer.parseInt(str.trim());
```

*If you try to parse this string without trimming then you will get `NumberFormatException`.*

Answer (score 0):

You trim it first afterwards you do the parsing.

```
Integer.parseInt(str.trim());
```

Answer (score 0):

U can use the trim function which will remove the space in front of the string.
Then you can convert the string into an integer.
The whole process is illustrated below:

String str =" 4443";
Integer i = Integer.parseInt(str.trim());

This would remove the space and later convert strinto an int..
Hope it helps.